# i have used a expression to decrement the for loop in javascript and it is not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop, shellsort

in my shell sort code, i have used a expression to decrement the 1st for loop and it's seems not working that's why my loop runs infinitely, can someone explain why the decrementing expression is not working ?. Here is the Code.....

```
const shellSort = function (arr) {
  let gap;
  for (gap = Math.floor(arr.length / 2); gap >= 1; Math.floor(gap / 2)) {
    for (let j = gap; j < n; j++) {
      for (let i = j - gap; i >= 0; i - gap) {
        if (arr[i + gap] > arr[i]) break;
        else [arr[i], arr[i + gap]] = [arr[i + gap], arr[i]];
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Both loop steps are incorrect, you can't have just

```
Math.floor(gap / 2)
```

because what you mean is

```
gap = Math.floor(gap / 2)
```

Same applies to the `i` loop.

Also, `n` is undefined there.

Your code corrected

```
var shellSort = function (arr) {
  let gap;
  for (gap = Math.floor(arr.length / 2); gap >= 1; gap = Math.floor(gap / 2)) {
    for (let j = gap; j < arr.length; j++) {
      for (let i = j - gap; i >= 0; i = i - gap) {
        if (arr[i + gap] > arr[i]) break;
        else [arr[i], arr[i + gap]] = [arr[i + gap], arr[i]];
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
};
```